# Playing Stream .m3u8 Audio File in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, m3u8, mpmovieplayer

I am confused about this. I have an URL which contains a .m3u8 file in it and when I try to stream the URL with:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeVolumeOnly];
[player setFullscreen:YES];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

It seems I can't because nothing starts playing. But when I use:

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController* controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The `viewcontroller` starts playing the file. What's the difference? Why can't I do it in my `viewcontroller`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could also try to define a `strong` property to point to the `MPMoviePlayerController` object, otherwise it will be immediately released and thus it won't play. `@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *player;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerController` lets you start playing, stopping and streaming of the content, which is meant to be incorporated into your own view hierarchy.

Since iOS 3.2 `MPMoviePlayerViewController` became available, which handles the presentation for you.

In your code above, for the first case, it is not added to the view hierarchy.

Ex:

```
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

Another difference is `MPMoviePlayerController` is a property of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Think of `MPMoviePlayerController` as a player that gives you the controls and
`MPMoviePlayerViewController` provides you, in addition to controls, also the presentation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code section you just have a `MPMoviePlayerController`, you should present it on screen, and actually add the `MPMoviePlayerController` View to your presented `UIVIewcontroller`'s View

```
[self.view addSubView:player.view]
```

In your second code section you have actually `UIViewController` With `MPMoviePlayerController` in it as [composition design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) .